# module 'pyramid' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, arima, pyramid-arima

Getting  error

```
module 'pyramid' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Error:

[image]

```
stepwise_model = auto_arima(palm_price_ts, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                       max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                       start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                       d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                       error_action='ignore',  
                       suppress_warnings=True, 
                       stepwise=False)
```

Comment: It sounds like you may have messed up your [pyramid](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pyramid/tree/master) install, perhaps by accidentally getting it mashed together with the [other project calling itself pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid).

Comment: I am currently experiencing this exact error, but at any rate, despite the uninformative format of this question, it would be nice if a solution to similarly messed up installs would be proposed by someone.

Answer (score 2):

As someone that has just experienced this after installing `pyramid` first, via pip, instead of `pyramid-arima`, the solution is just to uninstall both and only install one of them (presumably the arima-focused one).

Comment: thanks..it works..after uninstalling both and reinstall pyramid-arima..

Answer (score 2):

1.uninstall both pyramid and pyramid-arima
2.after that reinstall pyramid-arima
3.restart kernel